# xcode bug. App Icon layer has no reference

Tags: xcode, tvos

I am trying to make a tvOS App using xcode 7.2.1. 
In tvOS,  the App Icon has multiple layers, but Xcode's tool for handling such images is very buggy..

I have somehow managed to create a layer that does not refer to an image, and now I cannot remove that layer. The error message says:

> The file “Back.imagestacklayer” could not be moved to the trash
>   because it was not found.

Nor can I add an image to that layer. Any tips?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer. I *right-clicked* on *App Icon -Small* and selected *"show in finder"*. That took me to a *Contents.json* file that I could open in a *text editor* to remove the unwanted layer.